# Facebook post parameter "from" not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-wall

In the application I'm working on the user can post to other users walls to recommend jobs.

But these posts always has the profile image of the user that recived the post and not the one that was sending it (using the application).

I do set the sender user's name and id in the "from parameter" but its not working.

Can I atlest change so that it looks like it is the application that makes the post?

I'm using the facebook c# SDK

Answer (score 0):

Can you post an example screenshot? Reason I ask is it sounds like it's actually ommitting your image and it just looks like it's using the wrong one.

Facebook won't let you use an image that's residing on their CDN in a feed post. If you're trying to use your own application's icon, you must reference it from a URL that's not on Facebook.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Here is a [screenshot](http://www.veus.se/Facebook.jpg). As you can see it is the same image on the wall post as the profile image which is wrong as it is the application that is making the posts.

Comment: I know it's a pain, but can you post some of your code?

It may also be helpful to try and run it between two test users to ensure it's not your own account getting in the way of things (if you haven't already)